# Release Management- DACPAC Deployer failed over untrusted domain connectivity

Tags: visual-studio-2013, dacpac, ms-release-management

I have tried Database deployment to a server which is in a different domain using DACPAC Deployer. The server connectivity established through ghost accounts and i had successful deployments to the same server using XCOPY Deployer earlier.

DACPAC  Deployment have been rejected and I have got following error message.

The installation  command \"C:\Users\rmghost\AppData\Local\Temp\ReleaseManagement\ROMEO.DB Deployer\201408121235204725703-3\sqlpackage.exe /Action:Publish /SourceFile:".dacpac"  /TargetServerName:"" /TargetDatabaseName:""\" failed with the exit code \"-2146232576\".

Please share your thoughts to resolve this issue.

Comment: Does the account that deployer is running as have access to the database server?

Comment: Yes, account having access to the DB server. I had successful deployment to the same server using XCOPY Deployer. Using the same account i can remote login to the DB server and create DB mannually through Management studio. Deployment agent is running in the same account only...!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom.dll" was missing in the target DB server, which is a prerequisite for DACPAC deployment. So I installed " Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Transact-SQL ScriptDom" and triggered the release from RM. The release was successful.

Thank you very much for the support... !!!

Answer (score 2):

Edit:
You can also look at your empty TargetServerName and TargetDatabaseName. Those values should be given within your release template.

Here is one way to debug further - this will remove RM from the equation:

1. Change the deployer log output verbosity to verbose by following this [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/12/13/how-to-enable-detailed-logs-and-collect-traces-from-various-release-management-components.aspx).
2. Execute your failing deployment again.
3. We need to know what was the command executed and from which working directory it was executed. This can be retrieved by looking at the deployer log (available on the target server where the deployment occurred at this location: %Temp%\Microsoft\ReleaseManagement\12.0\Logs\DeploymentAgent.exe.log). In this log, look at the time of the deployment for the following two entries (or similar):

   > ```
   > 2012-05-12 10:40:12 - Verbose - RM.DeploymentAgent.Services.Deployer.ComponentProcessor.InstallComponent:
   > Deployment: **********Installation will be done from this folder: "C:\Users\DeployerUser\AppData\Local\Temp\InRelease\XBAP\20120620073259"
   > 2012-05-12 10:40:12 - Verbose - RM.DeploymentAgent.Services.Deployer.ComponentProcessor.InstallComponent:
   > Deployment: **********Installing component using command "xbapdeploy.exe -pn XbapDemo -d c:\temp\xbapdemo3"
   > ```
4. Next is to open a command prompt as the user running the Deployer Windows service, navigate to the folder shown above and execute the command.

This will mimic the Deployment Agent behavior and should give you more information to help figure out the problem. Let us know what you find.